# How to encrypt password to store in database using spring boot and hibernate

Tags: spring-boot, bcrypt

I have a registration page where I am getting user details. I need to use spring security to encrypt my password and store it in database. I am using BCryptPasswordEncoder but that is showing raw password cannot be null.  Output java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: rawPassword cannot be null. I dont know where I am doing wrong. Stuck in this for more than 3 days
In my controller class

```
     @RequestMapping(value="/registerNewCustomer")
     public String showCustomerRegistration(Customer customer) {
        customer.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(customer.getPassword()));
        customerService.saveCustomer(customer);
        return "customer";
    }

    
    My security config class has following information
```

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

```
    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    // Enable jdbc authentication
        @Autowired
        public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        }
    
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll();
    }

}
```

Comment: It looks like the argument that you are sending to the encode method is null. If you open the definition of  the `encode` method, you will see that the method throws exception if the password is null.

Answer (score -2):

Using bcript you can encrypt your password this is one-way encryption when you try to check for a password then you need to encrypt than you can match

```
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder(16);
    return encoder;
}
```

Comment: The third sentence of the question says " I am using BCryptPasswordEncoder". The example code contains a PasswordEncoder creation which is nearly identical to what you posted. You are advising to use something that is already being used.